# What does mean $\mu_{\varepsilon }$ is the measure induced by $\{\varepsilon B_t\}_t$ on $C_0[0,1]$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $C_0[0,1]$ the space of continuous function on $[0,1]$ s.t. $f(0)=0$ equipped with the norm of supremum. What mean that $\mu_\varepsilon $ is the measure induced by $\{\varepsilon B_t\}_t$ on $C_0[0,1]$ where $B_t$ is a brownian motion and $\varepsilon >0$ ? Is it that $$\mu_\varepsilon (A)=\mathbb P\{\varepsilon W_t\in A\}$$
for $A$ a borel set, or $$\mu_\varepsilon (A_1\times ...\times A_n)=\mathbb P\{\varepsilon W_{t_1}\in A_1,...,\varepsilon W_{t_n}\in A_n\}$$
for $A_i$ borel sets ?

Answer (score 1):

None are correct. I suspect you to have a confusion on the space where things are. The measure you defined are measure on $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^n$ respectively induced by $\varepsilon W_t$ and $(\varepsilon W_{t_1},...,\varepsilon W_{t_n})$ respectively (notice that in what you defined, $t$ and $t_i$ are fixed). To make thing rigorous, Let $\mathcal B$ the Borel sets of $\mathcal C_0[0,1]$ where the topology on $\mathcal C_0[0,1]$ is given by the supremum norm. Notice $U$ is open in $\mathcal C_0[0,1]$ if for all $f\in U$, there is $\delta >0$ s.t. $$B_\delta (f)=\left\{g\in \mathcal C_0[0,1]\mid \sup_{[0,1]}|f-g| <\delta \right\}.$$

Then, $$\mu_\varepsilon (A)=\mathbb P\{(\varepsilon W_t)_{t\in [0,1]}\in A\},\quad A\in \mathcal B.$$